# Dynamic CRM how to check the fields name while inserting data via api

Tags: php, dynamics-crm

I need to insert data to crmdqe_quoteheaders entity.When i listing entity via postman it returns the following JSON,

```
{
"@odata.etag": "W/"495053693"",
"crmd_totalamount_base": 6184.71,
"crmdqe_totalcostprice_base": 2059.72,
"_crmd_billto_value": "3ab6f6cb-a445-ed11-bba3-00224822704f",
"crmdqe_totaldiscountedprice_base": 6184.71,
"crmd_sendtobc": false,
"crmdqe_dateactiveto": "2022-11-09T08:00:00Z",
"_crmdqe_contactlookup_value": "8f7b82be-a445-ed11-bba2-0022482d3d6c",
"crmdqe_supressprintingquotetotals": false,
"crmdqe_estimatedclosedate": "2022-11-30T00:00:00Z",
"crmdqe_totalmargin_base": 4124.99,
"crmdqe_pricelistused": 122960000,
"crmdqe_totalcostmargin_base": 0,
"modifiedon": "2022-10-13T22:31:58Z",
"crmdqe_totalcostmargin": 0,
"crmdqe_quotevalidityindays": 122960000,
"_owninguser_value": "9b542182-412f-eb11-a813-000d3a1ab768",
"crmdqe_totaldiscountedprice": 6184.71,
"crmd_totalcostpriceincterms": 0,
"crmdqe_totallistprice": 6184.71,
"_ownerid_value": "9b542182-412f-eb11-a813-000d3a1ab768",
"crmdqe_totalcostmarginpct": 0,
"new_createopportunity": false,
"crmdqe_quoteheaderid": "0a08e590-b648-ed11-bba1-000d3a985290",
"crmd_verticalmarket": 1001,
"crmd_totalmarginincterms": 0,
"crmd_totalshippingcost": 0,
"crmd_taxamount_base": 0,
"timezoneruleversionnumber": 0,
"crmdqe_quotenumber": "QH-01053",
"processid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"statuscode": 122960000,
"createdon": "2022-10-10T16:14:11Z",
"crmd_totaldiscountedpriceincterms": 0,
"crmdqe_totalcostprice": 2059.72,
"crmdqe_totalmargin": 4124.99,
"crmd_revision": 0,
"crmd_marginpercent": 66.7,
"crmdqe_dateactivefrom": "2022-10-11T06:00:11Z",
"crmd_taxamount": 0,
"crmd_totalshippingcost_base": 0,
"versionnumber": 495053693,
"crmdqe_quotemargin": 66.7,
"_crmdqe_accountlookup_value": "907b82be-a445-ed11-bba2-0022482d3d6c",
"crmd_keywords": "QH-01053 - 0,",
"crmd_totalamount": 6184.71,
"crmd_approvalrequiredcode": 100000001,
"crmdqe_totallistprice_base": 6184.71,
"_transactioncurrencyid_value": "f98c011e-25e0-e211-9cd8-b4b52f67b674",
"_crmd_zipcode_value": "fc912ed6-7417-ea11-a811-000d3a579cc4",
"_crmd_shipto_value": "b04cfdd1-a445-ed11-bba3-00224822704f",
"exchangerate": 1,
"crmdqe_quoteheader_id": "QH-01053 - 0",
"_modifiedby_value": "4a06ecae-22e0-e211-8efd-b4b52f67d688",
"crmd_totalmarginincterms_base": 0,
"_createdby_value": "9b542182-412f-eb11-a813-000d3a1ab768",
"crmd_margin_base": 4124.99,
"crmd_margin": 4124.99,
"crmd_totalcostpriceincterms_base": 0,
"crmd_totaldiscountedpriceincterms_base": 0,
"statecode": 0,
"_owningbusinessunit_value": "b5b75f89-70d5-e211-8827-b4b52f67d656",
"_crmdqe_opportunitylookup_value": "917b82be-a445-ed11-bba2-0022482d3d6c",
"crmd_tags": null,
"_crmd_shippingtaxcodeid_value": null,
"crmdqe_datewonlost": null,
"crmdqe_marketingtext": null,
"crmdqe_commercialtext": null,
"crmd_invoicingstatus": null,
"crmd_revisiondetails": null,
"crmd_totalonorders_base": null,
"crmdqe_totaldiscountedpriceandshipping": null,
"crmd_shippingtax_base": null,
"crmd_remainingtoorder": null,
"crmdqe_quotecreationdate": null,
"_crmd_lastquoterevisionid_value": null,
"crmdqe_clonedquoteguid": null,
"_crmd_sourcerecordid_value": null,
"crmdqe_totaldiscountedpriceandshipping_base": null,
"crmd_gsa": null,
"_modifiedonbehalfby_value": null,
"crmd_executivesummary": null,
"importsequencenumber": null,
"utcconversiontimezonecode": null,
"crmd_termmonths": null,
"_createdonbehalfby_value": null,
"traversedpath": null,
"crmdqe_shippingcost": null,
"_crmd_order_standard_value": null,
"crmd_sow": null,
"new_processstatus": null,
"crmdqe_customerreference": null,
"_owningteam_value": null,
"new_specialinstructions": null,
"_crmd_approvedbyid_value": null,
"_crmdqe_quoteownerlookup_value": null,
"new_statementofworkcomplete": null,
"crmdqe_shippingcost_base": null,
"crmd_remainingtoorder_base": null,
"_crmd_pricelistid_value": null,
"new_invoiceinstructions": null,
"overriddencreatedon": null,
"crmd_incoterms": null,
"new_description": null,
"_stageid_value": null,
"_crmd_shippingid_value": null,
"crmd_totalonorders": null,
"_crmdqe_losttocompetitorlookup_value": null,
"crmdqe_quoterevision": null,
"crmd_remainingpercentage": null,
"crmd_shippingtax": null,
"_new_billingcontact_value": null
}
```

When try to insert data,
Method:POST
URL:https://alliedmodular.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/crmdqe_quoteheaders
Data:

```
{
  "crmdqe_accountlookup_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(accid)",
  "crmdqe_contactlookup_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(cid)",
  "crmdqe_opportunitylookup_value@odata.bind": "/opportunities(oppid)",
  "transactioncurrencyid_value": "f98c011e-25e0-e211-9cd8-b4b52f67b674",
  "crmdqe_quoteownerlookup_value": "/accounts(acid)",
  "crmdqe_quotevalidityindays": 122960000,
  "crmdqe_totallistprice": 1000
}
```

But it returns following error,
"message": "Error identified in Payload provided by the user for Entity :'crmdqe_quoteheaders', For more information on this error please follow this help link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2195293 ----> InnerException : Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'crmdqe_accountlookup_account' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.

I need to know how to get all field name for inserting.

Comment: you can use my tool Dataverse REST Builder to generate the request with the correct field names https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB you can export also to Postman

Comment: To be sure...are you replacing those "accid" for a true GUID identifier of an account, right? E.g., "/accounts(bbf604ca-2b2c-4404-baf7-aea68dbff875)"

Comment: Yes>The account id is added